# Vagrant + Puppet + Apache : 403 error

Tags: apache, virtualhost, vagrant, puppet

I have a problem with Apache, using Vagrant and Puppet.

With Vagrant, I mount my app folder like this :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./../", "/home/vagrant/myapp/", id: "myapp-sources", :owner => "root", :group => "root"
```

With I provision my vhost with puppet. It looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myapp
    DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/myapp/web
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    ServerName myapp.vagrant
    ServerAlias myapp.vagrant *.myapp.vagrant

    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/myapp-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myapp-access_log common

<Directory /home/vagrant/myapp/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access myapp.vagrant from my browser (I modified my /etc/hosts) I get a 403 error. In /var/log/apache2/myapp-error_log, I read this :

```
[Tue Dec 31 10:33:00.841882 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 998] [client 192.168.33.1:55878] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/vagrant/myapp/web/
```

I have no .htaccess file in my web folder.

I don't know where to look to solve this.

By the way, accessing my VM via it's IP in my browser shows the Apache "It works !" page in /var/www (user root, group root) and I have a virtual host to redirect myapp.vagrant:8000 to /usr/share/phpmyadmin (user root, group root) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using Apache 2.4? A simple search revealed it is likely a new permission model that's causing grief: http://dabase.com/blog/AH01630:_client_denied_by_server_configuration/